# Methods of function expansion

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

So far, I've learned about two kinds of orthogonal bases/kernels for expanding functions (on finite intervals):

1. (generalized) Fourier series, i. e. orthogonal sets of trigonometric functions.
2. Legendre polynomials.

So I wanted to ask if I'm missing any other common orthogonal base systems? (I'm only dealing with finite intervals)

I've also noticed that when using cylindrical coordinates $r, \theta$ for disk-like domains, the kernels of the Fourier series contain Bessel functions (c. f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Bessel_series). Are these necessary? Or could I just use the same trigonometric/Legendre kernels as for Cartesian coordinates? By my understanding, a complete orthogonal basis should stay complete and orthogonal if the variable has a different name.

Comment: If I understand your second question correctly, you are asking whether you can write the solution $u(r, \theta)$ to, e.g. Laplace's equation in polar coordinates using a Fourier series rather than an expansion in Bessel functions. In principle you could, but the reason for using an expansion in Bessel functions is that each term in the series satisfies the equation, making the analysis easier.

Comment: Well yes, to satisfy the Laplace equation we need Bessel functions (which are eigenfunctions of the Laplacian equation and therefore form an orthogonal basis). But in prinicipal, a complete orthogonal basis works in any coordinate system, right? (since mathematically, we are just changing variable names)

Answer (score 1):

[Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) provides many examples of complete orthogonal sets of functions. Many of the familiar orthogonal bases arise in this way, including [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory#Bessel_equation) and [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Definition_via_differential_equation). There are [many more well-known examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_orthogonal_polynomials) including the Hermite, Laguerre, Jacobi and Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: Sturm Liouville theory was indeed where I started off. But some sets (like the Hermite polynomials) don't seem to originate from a Sturm-Liouville problem (since they are defined on an unbounded interval, which is not a classical Sturm-Liouville problem). Anyways, all bases seem to be somewhat similar since they are all made up of oscillating functions.