# Name of approximation by linearly adding basis functions and its traits e.g. fourier transfer

Tags: fourier-transform, linear-approximation

## Questions

What is the name of the operation which approximates a continuous function by a linear combination of basis functions?

[image]

What kind of traits do they have? [Methods of function expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995938/methods-of-function-expansion) mentions `orthogonal bases/kernels` from which I suppose each basis would be a orthogonal vector in a vector space. However, I am not sure if polynomial functions are orthogonal vectors.

---

Fourier transfer uses trigonometric functions $sin(\theta), cos(\theta)$.

- [Javascript demonstration of fourier transfere](https://eman-physics.net/web_app/fourier/fourier.html)

[image]

Bayesian regression uses gaussian.

[image]

Gaussian process looks using covariance.

[image]

[Polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) uses polynomial.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for keywords? "Eigenfunction expansion" or "eigenvector expansion"?

Comment: Hi @paulgarrett, yes I would like to know what this approximation is called and what research/study have been done to understand further. Is fourier transfer, gaussian process, etc are in the category of "Eigenfunction expansion"?